# SQL Syntax Error: "Error: near "CHARACTER": syntax error"

Tags: sql, error-handling, syntax-error

I am trying to create a table to separate a huge database I have in a textfile into just username:email instead of their entire user:email:hash:etc

I have this:

```
>>>CREATE TABLE `database`(
  `UserGUID` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Salt` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `Strikes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Locked` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UpdatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeletedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'System',
  `UpdatedBy` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeletedBy` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailAuthenticated` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FollowID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DefaultLocationID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthDay` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthMonth` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthYear` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `BirthDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailAuthKey` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrentCrowns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CurrentCardpoints` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LastFreeCrowns` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `plaintextpassword` varchar(500) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastAuthEmail` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `premiumcards` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `steamid` varchar(80) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExternalPromotionID` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `culture` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserGUID`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `Username` (`UserName`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`Email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Follow` (`FollowID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `EmailAuthenticated` (`EmailAuthenticated`),
  KEY `SteamID` (`steamid`),
  KEY `authkey` (`EmailAuthKey`),
  KEY `IX_CreatedDate` (`CreatedDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

I keep getting this error: Error: near "CHARACTER": syntax error

help?

Comment: MySQL? What version?

Comment: There is a missing backtick at the end of the table name (`database`) in the first line.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on MySQL 5.7

Comment: Not a great idea to call a table "database" as its a reserved word but it compiles fine in mysql5.6 (i named the table something else and removed the single stray backtick from the name of the table. it wasnt immediately obvious before i edited your post to clean up the formatting because markdown uses backticks for inline code): see here for demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=38cc44dbdab2875cb28d03f34953ccaa

Comment: Works fine in [MySQL 8.0 too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f2fb3e420e7c2b917371a02cbd89c492).

Comment: So maybe the error just comes from the typo on line 1?

Comment: to post code on SO, either surround multiple code lines with a line containing only 3 backticks at the top and bottom of the code, or use at least 4 spaces at the start of every code line. Prefixing a line with > is a quote (yellow box, vari-space font) not code (grey box , mono font)

Comment: The only way for me to put all of that text in a verticle line and not a paragraph was to delete the first backtick

Comment: @r.ron see my comment above or click here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58573296/revisions

Comment: like that? i think i fixed it